# Polymer and SQL databases

Tags: web-component, polymer-3.x

Being a complete newbie to FE development, I'm trying to build a simple app that lets me view and edit a data table from a database that I hope can be a Google cloud SQL database.

I've found a nice and working tutorial for firebase here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase-pwa/index.html?index=..%2F..index#29

Which is nice, but does not do datatables (that would allow sorting by row, searching for entries etc) and also is only working for firebase database, which I think isn't allowing SQL queries.

I could for the life of me not find a sample app that uses say the paper-data-table (https://github.com/David-Mulder/paper-datatable )with Polymer.

I would *really* appreciate any pointers to sample code that shows how to  connect a datatable to a database with bidirectional bindings.

Many thanks in advance to all that can help!

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot connect database and make SQL queries from the client side. You need to use a server-side engine like  `PHP` or `Node` and for retrieve, save or update data, you may use ajax request with `iron-ajax` polymer element.

Comment: Yes, understood, I'm not worried about how to talk to the backend to get data (well, I am  but I think I can figure that out), I just don't know how to do the plumbing between the table object I get as a result of a query and the datatable UI components. Hence me asking for a good tutorial or sample code to learn from. But thanks for the iron-ajax pointer.